# How to get database property "Disable background agents for this database"?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

Our custom infrastructure monitoring application watches scheduled agents that run in production. There is no problem in LotusScript to cycle through databases and agents to get their state.

Some databases have set mentioned property, so agents are enabled, but don't run.

Can anybody give some clues, how to read this property in LotusScript, so our application could report such databases?

There is solution in [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21380020), but it states it works only in 32 bit environment (Lotus Notes clients are only 32 bit, so it is sufficient). Unfortunately, our application runs in background on x64 Domino servers.

**Edit**: test in development environment was successful - snippet of code from technote does not crash on Windows x64 Domino and flag is reported correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Code from technote works with 32 and 64 bit windows Domino servers.

```
Function agentsDisabled( db As NotesDatabase ) As Boolean
    Dim buffer As ReplicaInfo ' declarations from technote http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21380020
    Dim hDB As Long
    Dim fullpath As String
    fullpath = String(1024, " ")
    OSPathNetConstruct 0, db.Server, db.Filepath, fullpath

    NSFDbOpen fullpath, hDB
    NSFDbReplicaInfoGet hDB, buffer
    agentsDisabled = ( buffer.Flags And &H0800) > 0
    NSFDbClose hDB
End Function
```

Not tested to set the flag, I just needed to detect whether it is set or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using Lotus Notes C API in LotusScript then you can look into this [Technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21380020).

There also a project on OpenNTF called [Notes Database Properties LotusScript Class](http://openntf.org/Projects/codebin/codebin.nsf/CodeSearch/0A43C22F85C611D686256EC1002566B5) which allows you to set various other database properties that you can set via Notes client.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question - need x64 solution. And yes, I am open to use API.

Comment: Thanks for update. In that project there is "Only WIN32 Platform" limitation. I have hard times to find any x64 compatible LS to API calls (the common project/examples/tutorials are 32 bit and will not work or crash on x64).

Answer (score 0):

The properties are mostly stored in the icon note. See this [technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21244071). Looks like you will need to test what changes in the $Flags item when you enable/disable the property.

**EDIT:** You could also try `NotesNoteCollection.SelectAllNotes(True)` and see if you get a note containing this property.

Comment: Thanks, but as @Naveen mentioned already, this flag is in replication info (oh, good ol' Notes architecture...)

Comment: OK and where is that stored? I added a suggestion to my answer.

Comment: As I said: replication info by calling NSFDbReplicaInfoGet( hDB, data )

Comment: Yes I saw that function call but I mean where is the data stored. In Notes I guess the only possibility is that it is stored in a note. That means you can modify it with LotusScript. It's just a question of finding that note.